# Problem with Visual Studio when run on another pc

Tags: visual-studio, oledb

i have problem in Visual Studio 2019 when i run my project in my pc. It can run very well. But when i share my project to my instructor, she couldn't run it and error was occur. The error said " 'Microsoft .ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on local machine. any solution from this problem?

Answer (score 1):

She needs to install the ACE drivers freely downloadable from Microsoft. See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

You need to ensure that if you compiled your project as x86 (32 bit) the the 32 bit ACE driver needs to be installed? If compiled as 64 bit, then 64 bit ACE driver should be installed.

Comment: my project compiled as Any CPU

Comment: Well, had your teacher downloaded and installed the 64 bit ACE drivers? If she is using Windows 10 the AnyCPU assembly will run in 64 bit mode.